# Devise: subdomain redirect after login

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, subdomain, acts-as-tenant

I am using Devise and ActsAsTenant for a multi-tenant saas rails 7 app and am having trouble redirecting users to the correct subdomain after login with Device.

Each `User` is associated with an `Account` that has a subdomain column. I have read through the documents for Devise and customized `after_sign_in_path_for` to route to the dashboard page after login. Whenever I try to add a subdomain to the redirect, I get an **Unsafe redirect** error.

```
Unsafe redirect to "http://test.lvh.me:3000/dashboard", pass allow_other_host: true to redirect anyway.
```

My `after_sign_in_path_for` method

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
    ....

    def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
        dashboard_url(subdomain: resource.account.subdomain)
    end
end
```

I have tried to pass `allow_other_host: true` but I get a similar error

```
dashboard_url(subdomain: resource.account.subdomain, allow_other_host: true)

Unsafe redirect to "http://test.lvh.me:3000/dashboard?allow_other_host=true", pass allow_other_host: true to redirect anyway.
```

Looking at other code and example I think I have to write it like this

```
redirect_to dashboard_url(subdomain: current_user.account.subdomain), allow_other_host: true
```

but then I get a `Render and/or redirect were called multiple times in this action` error.

I also tried modifying the `create` method for `SessionsController` and bypassing the `after_sign_in_path_for` completely but I still get the same **Unsafe Redirect** error.

```
class SessionsController < Devise::SessionsController
    def create
        self.resource = warden.authenticate!(auth_options)
        set_flash_message!(:notice, :signed_in)
        sign_in(resource_name, resource)
        yield resource if block_given?
        respond_to do |format|
          format.html do
            redirect_to dashboard_url(subdomain: current_user.account.subdomain), only_path: false, allow_other_host: true
          end
        end
    end
end
```

My Routes:

```
devise_for :users, path: '', path_names: {
    sign_in: 'login',
    sign_out: 'logout'
  }, controllers: {
    sessions: 'sessions'
  }
get 'dashboard', to: 'static_pages#dashboard'
root to: "static_pages#index"
```

Answer (score 1):

You could disable the redirect protection, [introduced on Rails 7.0](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html#config-action-controller-raise-on-open-redirects)

```
Rails.application.config.action_controller.raise_on_open_redirects = false
```

But before doing this, you should read about [open redirect attacks](https://www.stackhawk.com/blog/rails-open-redirect-guide-examples-and-prevention/)